# como puedo clickear la opción de mensajes de instagram con selenium

Tags: python, web, selenium-webdriver, instagram, web-scrapping

he estado intentado obtener tanto el xpath relativo y absoluto del DOM html de mensajes de instagram ya que intento enviar mensajes masivos, pero no he podido dar con ello, algun consejo para obtenerlo de forma mas facil, he intentado mas que todo con el xpath relativo.

```
messages=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body[@class=_a3wf system-fonts--body segoe]//a[@class=ce de 20 notificaciones nuevas]//div[@class=x9f619 x1xmf6yo x11i5rnm x1e56ztr x1mh8g0r x3nfvp2 x1z11no5 xjy5m1g x1mnwbp6 x4pb5v6 xz9dl7a xn6708d xsag5q8 x1ye3gou x1l895ks x159b3zp xdoji71 x1v9afh1 x1sxb60h x1ug36kh xubc8zo x1dejxi8 x9k3k5o xs3sg5q x11hdxyr x12ldp4w x1wj20lx x1dn74xm xif99yt x172qv1o x10djquj x1lhsz42 xzauu7c]')
    messages.click()
    sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar un xpath relativo como en tu código, es recomendable usar un xpath absoluto que incluya todos los elementos padres del elemento que deseas seleccionar. De esta manera, puedes asegurarte de que seleccionas el elemento correcto incluso si hay elementos con el mismo nombre en diferentes partes de la página.

Si no puedes encontrar el xpath absoluto del elemento que deseas seleccionar, puedes utilizar la herramienta de desarrollador de tu navegador para inspeccionar el DOM de la página y encontrar el xpath correcto. Para hacer esto, sigue estos pasos:

Abre la página de Instagram en tu navegador y espera a que cargue por completo.
Haz clic derecho en el elemento que deseas seleccionar y elige "Inspeccionar" en el menú contextual.
En la consola de desarrollador, busca el elemento en el DOM y haz clic derecho en él.
Elige "Copiar" en el menú contextual y luego "Copiar xpath" para obtener el xpath absoluto del elemento.
Usa este xpath en tu código de Selenium para seleccionar el elemento correctamente.

Espero que esto te ayude a clickear la opción de mensajes